# Why would Dwight own an iMac?

Tags: the-office

I am watching The Office (US version), Season 4 Episode 7. This episode originally aired on Oct 18th, 2007. In this episode Jim and Pam go to Dwight's BnB for a night stay.
During their stay we get to get inside look of Dwight's house. Everything seems reasonable (for Dwight) but I notice a fancy computer in Dwight's room, possibly iMac?

Now my question is, Is it really an iMac? And if yes, why would Dwight own a iMac when he had worked on Windows most of the time and he does not look very tech savvy to me. And if it is not an iMac, what is this iMac looking computer?

[image]

Comment: It is an iMac as per The Office fandom wiki. https://theoffice.fandom.com/wiki/Schrute_Farms

Comment: FWIW, Dwight is very tech savvy. He's just more. . . tech-averse. It is strange that he'd own an iMac given his fondness for computer games.

Comment: This episode aired a little after the iPhone released, during which Steve Jobs aired an episode from "The Office" in the demo. Angela Kinsey and Jenna Fischer have acknowledged funny coincidences between the show and Steve. Perhaps an homage? Are out-of-universe explanations based on conjecture on topic?

Comment: @Aww_Geez yes, I didn’t know that Jobs had used The Office in the demo. That might be a reason for Dwight to own IMac but they could show it in Micheal’s house (presenting it as a pretty novelty item) or better in Ryan’s office (when he was Micheal’s boss) as he is earning way more than Dwight, is very interested in new tech (DM infinity).

Comment: In my decades of experience dealing with all kinds of people and their computers, I haven’t seen a correlation between level of tech savvy and preference for Windows or MacOS. Personally, using Windows at work all the time is one of the reasons why I prefer a Mac in my personal life.

Comment: *It may perfectly well be an iMac running Windows on bare metal. That is specifically supported on Intel Macs*.

Comment: @Aww_Geez I am still watching the show and in Season 4, episode 18, there is a scene where Jim pairs Dwight's cellphone with his own Bluetooth earphone. And forwards his office desk phone to his own phone. 
This seems like a normal thing for Jim and Dwight, but what surprised me was that Dwight, who has worked on Computers (both Windows and Mac) could/did not disconnect the Bluetooth device from his phone. He just had to switch off his phone's bluetooth OR disconnect the Jim's earphone. But instead Dwight breaks his cell phone. Now this makes me wonder if Dwight was really bad with tech.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Dwight probably brought an iMac because he is not an idiot.

As we know from the season 3 episode, Business School, Dwight was given some advice which he says "changed his life":

> Whenever I'm about to do something I think, "Would an idiot do that?". And if they would, I do not do that thing"

Presented with the option to buy an iMac, he possibly asked himself, "Would an idiot buy an iMac?", and decided that it was a non-idiot investment.

We know that Dwight is comfortable with computers, having spent many years using them for work, as well as a year playing *Second Life*, and time spent playing *StarCraft*.

We don't know exactly what he uses the iMac for, so it could be that he's using it for games he's comfortable with, or to answer Trip Advisor reviews of Schrute Farms.

Comment: I am still watching the show and in Season 4, episode 18, there is a scene where Jim pairs Dwight's cellphone with his own Bluetooth earphone. And forwards his office desk phone to his own phone. This seems like a normal thing for Jim and Dwight, but what surprised me was that Dwight, who has worked on Computers (both Windows and Mac) could/did not disconnect the Bluetooth device from his phone. He just had to switch off his phone's bluetooth OR disconnect the Jim's earphone. But instead Dwight breaks his cell phone. Now would an idiot break the phone instead of disconnecting the BT device.